# Verifying signed messages

Tags: signature, erc-20-approve

I sent signed messages to claim ownership of various tokens yesterday. I'm wondering how long to get them verified as I couldn't do it via the source contracts.

Comment: We will need some more context here in order to help you. Where did you send the messages and which tokens are you supposed to get ownership to? Is this some platform you are using?

Comment: Note the Ethereum.stackexchange.com is not a support for third party tokens or platforms. Contact any token project team directlyt.